# Stata: storing Beta estimates in a matrix and then displaying matrix in Word or Excel document

Tags: matrix, statistics, regression, stata

I did some research online and using a combination of `estout` and `tabstat` seems like the way to go here.

I am running the following regression

```
reg subject inSchool#treatment#male
```

I need the output to display the following

[image]

The betas are all in reference to a female, not in school, and in the control group, hence the `_cons` label.

Is storing the output in a matrix the best way to achieve this display and how would I do this?

Comment: The short answer is no. Stata's matrices, like those in any software I know, contain just one numeric element in each cell and don't allow a hierarchy of rows or columns. This question is arguably too broad and fails the criterion "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results" http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This question appears (a) too broad (a discussion of formatted tabulation output in Stata is too large a scope) (b) off-topic as a request for code but with no attempt to show what OP has tried.

Comment: My apologies. I have posted another question which is much more specific as to the actual programming challenge that I face. I've never been a very good programmer, but I teach at a high school which has performed an interesting study on its students and they want someone to analyze the results.

Comment: Statalist is another possible forum. Several of the Stata users who answer question here are also active there. However, posts asking for complete code solutions (or appearing to do so) for complicated questions may not fare well in any forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nick is correct that this question is too vague, but this should show you enough so that you can ask specific, answerable questions (just because you're a teacher :) ).

The command you're looking for to easily make nice tables is `eststo`, which is part of `estout` (install this package with `ssc install estout`). Below I store each regression output with `eststo` and assign a model title with `, title()`, then include these model titles with `esttab, mtitle`. Within `estout` there are enough features and options for at least 1,000 more questions. But this should get you started and find out which of those 1,000+ questions you have.

```
* I don't understand your data structure, but here's a guess
clear
set obs 2001
generate score = 60 + (100 - 60)*runiform()
generate subject = floor(3 * runiform()) + 1
generate inSchool = floor(2 * runiform())
generate treatment = floor(2 * runiform())
generate male = floor(2 * runiform())

* label 
label define subjects 1 "Math" 2 "Science" 3 "English"
label define males 0 "Female" 1 "Male" 
label define treatments 0 "Control" 1 "Treatment" 
label value subject subjects
label value male males
label value treatment treatments

* loop over combinations
* ssc install esttab
eststo clear
levelsof subject, local(subjects)
forvalues t =0/1 {
    forvalues m = 0/1 {
        foreach s of local subjects {
            * help extended_fcn
            local ss: label subjects `s'        
            local tt: label treatments `t'        
            local mm: label males `m'        
            regress score inSchool ///
                if (subject == `s') ///
                    & (treatment == `t') ///
                    & (male == `m')
            * help eststo        
            eststo, title("`tt', `mm', `ss'")        
        }
    }
}
* to screen
esttab, mtitle
* to files
esttab using "temp.rtf", mtitle
esttab using "temp.csv", mtitle
```

I guess I should add that this type of regression is usually endogenous unless you've really randomly assigned the treatment variables.